# Meteor How to call one template helper into another helper?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

How i can access one template helper into another. I have 2 templates

1. Right sidebar path is

`app\client\templates\shared\sidebar`

2. my_trb  path is

`app\client\templates\pages\my_trb`

on `my_trb` page i am showing list of all added memebrs in my account and same thing i need to call in sidebar helper. So is there way to call `my_trb` template helper into sidebar? This is helper in `my_trb`

```
Template.MyTribes.helpers({

  'myTrb' () {
    let tribIOwn = Meteor.user().trb_i_own; 
    let trb = [];
    tribIOwn.forEach(function (t) {
      trb.push(Trb.findOne({_id: t}));
    });
    return trb;
  },

});
```

This is full code of tribes_controller.js

```
TrbController = RouteController.extend({

  subscriptions: function() {
    this.subscribe('users').wait();
    this.subscribe('trb', this.params._id).wait();
  },

  waitOn: function () {
    this.subscribe('trb',Meteor.userId());
    this.subscribe('tribeArgs', this.params._id);
  },


  data: function () {
    return Trb.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
  },

  // You can provide any of the hook options

  onRun: function () {
    this.next();
  },
  onRerun: function () {
    this.next();
  },

  //onBeforeAction: function () {
  //  this.next();
  //},
  onBeforeAction: function () {
    if (!Meteor.userId()) {
      this.render('Splash');
    } else {
      if (!Meteor.user().username) {
        this.render('AddUsername');
      } else {
        this.next();
      }
    }
  },


  action: function () {
    this.render();
  },
  onAfterAction: function () {
  },
  onStop: function () {
  },
  editTribe: function () {
    this.render('EditTribe');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For common / shared code that needs to be accessed by more than one Template it makes sense to define a global helper using [Template.registerHelper](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Template-registerHelper).

For your helper this would look like this:

`app\client\templates\shared\helpers`

```
// import { Trb } from ....

Template.registerHelpers('myTrb', function myTrb () {
  const user = Meteor.user();
  if (! user) return [];
  const tribIOwn = user.trb_i_own; 
  const trb = [];
  tribIOwn.forEach(function (t) {
    trb.push(Trb.findOne({_id: t}));
  });
  return trb
})
```

(Note, that I changed a bit, since `Meteor.user().trb_i_own` would crash if there is no logged in user.)

Now you can remove the helper on the `my_trb` Template and call it from `my_trb` and the sidebar as well.

Comment: I have created global helper like you have mentioned above and when i console.log(tribesImIn) then it's showing Id's of all added members but not getting further values for that users. Do i need to call controller also in global helpers file? In each loop when trying to push using trb.push(Trb.findOne({_id: t})); and console.log(trb); it's showing undefined.

Comment: You need to subscribe to the publications that are related to the users globally, too or you will only get the minimum fields in Meteor.user()

Comment: how i can subscribe to the publications

Comment: As  as this is alreday published in app/server/publish.js file
Meteor.publish('trb', function (trbId) {
 return Trb.find({_id: trbId});
});

Comment: Yes you need to subscribe to this pub

Comment: There is no such thing named controller in your questions code so I can't say if it is correct or not.

Comment: Yes there are controller file in app/lib/controllers/tribes_controller.js and in it i have subscribe this.

waitOn: function () {
    this.subscribe('trb',Meteor.userId());
    
  },

Comment: Please add the complete code of this file into the question and not the comments.

Comment: i have added complete code of tribes_controller.js file above

Comment: It seems controller file is not calling in global_helpers.js. when i subscribe here global_helpers.js as Meteor.subscribe('trb'); it's working. So is it good to subscribe it in  global_helpers.js file.

Comment: If it's a global subscription it is ok to subscribe there. For local subscription you can use template instance.subscribe

Comment: okay but it's also subscribe in trb_controller.js. Do i need to remove it from here? Because it's working only if i subscribe it in global_helpers.js. Not sure why it's not working from controller file.

Comment: @user3714488 did my answer help you to solve your problem?

Comment: yes it works when i subscribe it in global_helpers.js

Comment: could you please accept this answer if it solved your problem? This also ensures that others with similar issue can easily see, that there is an accepted solution.

Comment: yes it's working only when i called Meteor.subscribe('trb');  in publish.js file.